# Extract 6 digit codes to a separate columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There are many, many questions and quality answers on Stackoverflow regarding how to extract numbers from a string, however but I am not able to find for the one looking for, so i have a spreadsheet where in a column descriptions are there along with specific codes in each cell.

These are 6-digit codes which should be extracted to a separate column. I can do that with the help of filterxml function if there is only 1 code inside a cell. But what formula should I use if there are more than 1 code in each cell?

Refer below, I need to extract both codes.

```
Advance payment based on contract # 990|33 dated 19.04.22 Invoice # HF 450|39 324500 526 324719 965
```

Using this formula

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(C3," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[string-length()=6]")
```

so it needs to be 324500 & 324719 but it spills anything with string length of 6

Comment: Will there ever be any leading zeros in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to change the xPath argument to include a parameter for only numeric data.

```
//s[number(.)=. and string-length()=6]
```

eg:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number(.)=. and string-length()=6]")
```

If any of the 6-digit numbers might have one or more leading zero's, then use the `TEXT` function also:

```
=TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number(.)=. and string-length()=6]"),"000000")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may ***try*** anyone of the following,

[image]

• Formula used in cell **B3**

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","x"),SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)-5),6)+0,{1,2})
```

Or, If you are using **O365** & presently in **Office Insiders**, **Beta Channel Version**, then may try this as well

• Formula used in cell **B2**

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,--TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),{2,1})
```